# How can I convert multiple raw values in single column

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net

My data is like this:

> [image: Original Data]

But I want to arrange all raw value in one column for a single mobile number like this:

> [image: image-2]

Comment: Does your actual data contain several phone numbers or just one?

Comment: Ha, just wrote an answer in Google Sheets - shoulda looked at the tag. It does handle it well though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the database type you are using, but you do specify excel as a tag. Is this a database question? You also don't provide any names for columns  so it's difficult to help.

Oracle has a [listagg function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php) which can be used to pivot row values into a list

```sql
SELECT column1, 
LISTAGG(column2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column2) as list_of_values
FROM your_table
group by column1;
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle of it in action.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f1723/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a new version of Excel, you may use `TEXTJOIN`:

Assuming that your data is at range `B1:B15`, use below formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",0,B1:B15)
```